# Verifying scrollbar is present script fails

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java, javascript

I'm trying to check whether a scrollbar is present when there are more than 2 elements in a pop up.

Here is the HTML code for the div which enables the scroll bar if when there are more than 2 elements.

```
<div class="MuiDialogContent-root-6843 px-3 pb-5 pt-0"><div class="text-center justify-content-center"><div class="col-md-6 mx-auto mt-3"><h5 class="MuiTypography-root-6319 mx-auto jss6317 jss6897 MuiTypography-h5-6328">Details</h5></div><div align="center"><div class="MuiTabs-root-6435 jss6898"><div class="MuiTabs-scrollable-6442" style="width: 99px; height: 99px; position: absolute; top: -9999px; overflow: scroll;"></div><div class="MuiTabs-scroller-6440 MuiTabs-scrollable-6442" style="margin-bottom: 0px;"><div class="MuiTabs-flexContainer-6437" role="tablist"><button class="MuiButtonBase-root-6413 MuiTab-root-6446 jss6845 MuiTab-textColorSecondary-6450 Mui-selected jss6849 MuiTab-wrapped-6452" tabindex="0" type="button" role="tab" aria-selected="true" id="simple-tab-any" aria-controls="simple-tabpanel-any"><span class="MuiTab-wrapper-6453 jss6846">Anytime</span><span class="MuiTouchRipple-root-6681"></span></button><button class="MuiButtonBase-root-6413 MuiTab-root-6446 jss6845 MuiTab-textColorSecondary-6450 MuiTab-wrapped-6452" tabindex="-1" type="button" role="tab" aria-selected="false" id="simple-tab-night" aria-controls="simple-tabpanel-night"><span class="MuiTab-wrapper-6453 jss6846">Night time</span><span class="MuiTouchRipple-root-6681"></span></button><button class="MuiButtonBase-root-6413 MuiTab-root-6446 jss6845 MuiTab-textColorSecondary-6450 MuiTab-wrapped-6452" tabindex="-1" type="button" role="tab" aria-selected="false" id="simple-tab-any_bonus" aria-controls="simple-tabpanel-any_bonus"><span class="MuiTab-wrapper-6453 jss6846">Anytime bonus</span><span class="MuiTouchRipple-root-6681"></span></button></div><span class="jss6454 jss6456 MuiTabs-indicator-6445 jss6899" style="left: 0px; width: 91.8125px;"></span></div></div></div><div class="pt-3" role="tabpanel" id="full-width-tabpanel-any" aria-labelledby="full-width-tab-any"><div class="scrollbar-container scroll-section ps" style="height: 380px;"><div class="jss6848"><div class="justify-content-center py-2 row"><div class="col-lg-7 col"><div class="card"><div class="py-3 card-body"><div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center"><p class="MuiTypography-root-6319 jss6317 jss6900 MuiTypography-body1-6321">99/- Internet Card</p><p class="MuiTypography-root-6319 font-weight-bold jss6317 jss6901">660 MB Total</p></div><div class="pt-2"><div class="MuiLinearProgress-root-6903 jss6902 MuiLinearProgress-colorSecondary-6905 MuiLinearProgress-determinate-6906" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="71" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"><div class="MuiLinearProgress-bar-6913 MuiLinearProgress-barColorSecondary-6915 MuiLinearProgress-bar1Determinate-6917" style="transform: translateX(-29%);"></div></div></div><div class="d-flex justify-content-between pt-2 align-items-center"><div class="d-inline-flex align-items-baseline flex-wrap"><h5 class="MuiTypography-root-6319 font-weight-bold pr-2 jss6317 jss6924 MuiTypography-h5-6328" style="color: rgb(136, 0, 102);">470.29 MB</h5><p class="MuiTypography-root-6319 jss6317 jss6925 MuiTypography-body2-6320" style="color: rgb(136, 0, 102);">remaining</p></div><p class="MuiTypography-root-6319 jss6317 jss6926">5 d : 13 hrs more</p></div></div></div></div></div><div class="justify-content-center py-2 row"><div class="col-lg-7 col"><div class="card"><div class="py-3 card-body"><div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center"><p class="MuiTypography-root-6319 jss6317 jss6927 MuiTypography-body1-6321">99/- Internet Card</p><p class="MuiTypography-root-6319 font-weight-bold jss6317 jss6928">637 MB Total</p></div><div class="pt-2"><div class="MuiLinearProgress-root-6903 jss6902 MuiLinearProgress-colorSecondary-6905 MuiLinearProgress-determinate-6906" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"><div class="MuiLinearProgress-bar-6913 MuiLinearProgress-barColorSecondary-6915 MuiLinearProgress-bar1Determinate-6917" style="transform: translateX(0%);"></div></div></div><div class="d-flex justify-content-between pt-2 align-items-center"><div class="d-inline-flex align-items-baseline flex-wrap"><h5 class="MuiTypography-root-6319 font-weight-bold pr-2 jss6317 jss6929 MuiTypography-h5-6328" style="color: rgb(136, 0, 102);">637 MB</h5><p class="MuiTypography-root-6319 jss6317 jss6930 MuiTypography-body2-6320" style="color: rgb(136, 0, 102);">remaining</p></div><p class="MuiTypography-root-6319 jss6317 jss6931">19 d : 13 hrs more</p></div></div></div></div></div></div><div class="ps__rail-x" style="left: 0px; bottom: 0px;"><div class="ps__thumb-x" tabindex="0" style="left: 0px; width: 0px;"></div></div><div class="ps__rail-y" style="top: 0px; right: 0px;"><div class="ps__thumb-y" tabindex="0" style="top: 0px; height: 0px;"></div></div></div></div><div class="pt-3" role="tabpanel" hidden="" id="full-width-tabpanel-night" aria-labelledby="full-width-tab-night"></div><div class="pt-3" role="tabpanel" hidden="" id="full-width-tabpanel-any_bonus" aria-labelledby="full-width-tab-any_bonus"></div></div></div>
```

below is the code.

```
public DataDetailViewPage validateScrollbar() {

    // find details pop up in data card
    detailsPopup = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div[role='tabpanel']")).get(3);  
    
    //get scroll bar using java script(vertical scroll bar)
    String script = "return document.documentElement.scrollHeight>document.documentElement.clientHeight;";
    
    JavascriptExecutor scrollBarPresent = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

    //get scroll bar is present to a boolean variable
    Boolean scroll = (Boolean) (scrollBarPresent.executeScript(script));

    //size of the detail cards present inside details pop up
    int elementCount = detailsPopup.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='py-3 card-body']")).size();

    //here we check whether scroll bar is present if element count is grater than 2.if present return true or else return false
    if (elementCount > 2) {
        Assert.assertTrue(scroll);
    } else {
        Assert.assertFalse(scroll);
    }
    
    //return new object of DataDetailViewPage
    return new DataDetailViewPage();
}
```

Right now I have 2 elements and result should be false I'm getting "expected false but found true" error.

Can you tell me what I did wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the HTML code you shared, I tried the below and it worked out. I got the desired result.

I also added in additional elements to increase the content and enable scrollbar and got the right result for that as well.

```
String JS_ELEMENT_IS_SCROLLABLE = "return arguments[0].scrollHeight > arguments[0].offsetHeight;";
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
WebElement container = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@role='tabpanel'][1]/div"));
Boolean isScrollable = (Boolean)jse.executeScript(JS_ELEMENT_IS_SCROLLABLE, container);
if (isScrollable) {
    System.out.println("Scrollbar present");
} else {
    System.out.println("Scrollbar Not present");
}
```

Comment: Once I applied your java script code it worked. Thanks. I replaced String script = "return document.documentElement.scrollHeight>document.documentElement.clientHeight;"; to this String script = "return arguments[0].scrollHeight > arguments[0].offsetHeight;"; and changed the scroll execute script accordingly.